# Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type function. Defaulting to continuous

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
ggplot(data = Daily_inca, mapping = aes(x = Active_Minutes, y = Calories)) +
  geom_freqpoly(mapping = aes(color = cut), binwidth = 500)
```

Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type function. Defaulting to continuous.

Comment: Welcome to SO! It would be easier to help you if you provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of your data or some fake data.

Comment: But from the error message and your code I would guess that this is related to `color=cut` and that there is no column names `cut` in your data so that R thinks you mean the `cut()` function. Maybe you could check that `cut` is indeed the name of a column in your data.